# Is adding extra information to the question considered a good edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, do you Approve edits that add relatively many extra information to a question, for an example, a screenshot, links, error messages ?

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1541330) with a new image added (skipped from the queue though) and some other questions that can probably lead to a different idea than what OP wanted to explain.

It's true that this particular edit is helpful but I'm just curious if edits should be mainly to make major improvements or to fine-tune the answer/question.
User who edited the question should have done that with a hope that his/her edits would be useful or it could be his several hours of testing.

If you Reject the edit, how do you appreciate the editor's effort with the edit ?

Comment: That image is not extra information. It is the same image the original asker linked to- the asker just didn't have the rep to post the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), some common reasons to edit are:

- to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
- to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
- to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
- to add related resources or hyperlinks

So, in general, editors should **not** add major information to the question or answer, but instead they should limit themselves to minor content changes.

Your specific case is, however, different. The OP asked a question, mentioning a screenshot posted in a page that was linked in the question. The editor, then, posted the image directly inside the question, so whoever reads the question does not need to open a new page to understand what the question is about. I would call it a **good edit**.

Answer (score 0):

No. I reject them as "Invalid Edit." The user should instead post the edit as a comment, and the original poster of the answer/question can then add the edit into their post if they see fit.